# How to use WBEM in dll launched by another DLL from different compiler?

Tags: dll, com, wbem

I have a worker DLL(A) compiled by VC6 which using WBEM.
    And I want call function in DLL(A) from another DLL(B : compiled by VC2013). it crash on IWbemLocator :: ConnectServer().

```
And I have done some testing followed:
EXE compiled by VC6 - > DLL(A)  OK
EXE compiled by VC2013 - > DLL(A)  OK
EXE compiled by VC2013 - > DLL(B) - > DLL(A)  crash
I don't why, any one can give me some advise? Thank you very much!
```

Comment: if you run in debug mode, do you get any kinda of stack trace, when the crash happens?

Comment: ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_RtlReportException@12() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_RtlInvalidHandlerDetected@12() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_RtlIsValidHandler@8() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_RtlDispatchException@8() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8() Unknown
  rpcrt4.dll!NdrpConformantStringBufferSize(struct _MIDL_STUB_MESSAGE *,unsigned char *,unsigned char const *) Unknown

Comment: rpcrt4.dll!_NdrConformantStringBufferSize@12() Unknown
  rpcrt4.dll!NdrpPointerBufferSize(struct _MIDL_STUB_MESSAGE *,unsigned char *,unsigned char const *) Unknown
  rpcrt4.dll!_NdrPointerBufferSize@12() Unknown
  rpcrt4.dll!@NdrpSizing@8() Unknown
  rpcrt4.dll!_NdrClientCall2() Unknown
  ole32.dll!ObjectStublessClient(void * ParamAddress, long Method) Line 474 C++

Comment: ole32.dll!_ObjectStubless@0() Line 154 Unknown
  wbemprox.dll!CDCOMTrans::DoActualConnection(unsigned short *,unsigned short *,unsigned short *,unsigned short *,long,unsigned short *,struct IWbemContext *,struct IWbemServices * *) Unknown
  wbemprox.dll!CDCOMTrans::DoConnection(unsigned short *,unsigned short *,unsigned short *,unsigned short *,long,unsigned short *,struct IWbemContext *,struct IWbemServices * *) Unknown

Comment: wbemprox.dll!CLocator::ConnectServer(unsigned short * const,unsigned short * const,unsigned short * const,unsigned short * const,long,unsigned short * const,struct IWbemContext *,struct IWbemServices * *) Unknown
  10029f1b() Unknown

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to change the format for reading